# How to ensure that send method of the protocol is thread safe

Tags: python, twisted

I'm working on TCP client-server application using the IntNReceiver protocol. Server is accepting multiple TCP connections from client. I would like to let other threads use the protocol's sendString method, on both client and the server. I tried to use synchronized queue, monitored in separate thread and reactor.callFromThread() to call the sendString from there. This seems to work but there is a weird delay of about 20 seconds before the actual sendString actually sends the string. It does not block, returns immediately. I ran strace and the send() system call is definitely delayed. What is the proper way to do this kind of thing with twisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `callFromThread` directly as your queue.  The reactor is already synchronizing on and monitoring it.  Anywhere you want to call `foo.sendString()` from a non-reactor thread, just do `reactor.callFromThread(foo.sendString)`.  Building additional infrastructure to do this (your own custom synchronized queues, for example) is just additional code that might break – as you have already discovered.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the way to go. In addition, the thread from which I was invoking `reactor.callFromThread(foo.sendString)` was created using regular Python threading API. I switched to `reactor.callInThread` instead and everything works fine now. Does it mean that `callFromThread` guarantees thread safety only when called from threads created by `callInThread` or `deferToThread`? Or maybe after a little cleaning I fixed something else that was causing this problem... ;)

Comment: `callFromThread` should work fine from any Python thread, not just those created by `callInThread` (or indeed, created by anything related to Twisted).